# Process.Start filename using %temp%

Tags: c#, path, filenames, processstartinfo, start-process

For some odd reaseon this code fails:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"%temp%\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi";
```

and this code succes:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi";
```

Is there any reason I am missing?

**Note** I just copied the path, I don't think the rest of the code is needed but I'll put it anyway:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"%temp%\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/passive";
p.Start();
```

Comment: Possibly what you need: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348003/using-environment-variable-in-a-file-path

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013383/how-can-an-application-access-the-environment-variable-set-by-another-applicatio

Process start does not expand environment variables.

Comment: I haven't found it before posting (I've been searching for a while)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) does not expand strings with environment variables (i.e. `%temp%`).

If you want to use environment variables to build the [`FileName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx) then you'll have to get the environment variables (using the [`GetEnvironmentVariable` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) on the [`Environment` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)) and perform the substitution yourself, like so:

```
// Construct the path.
string temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp");
string path = Path.Combine(temp, "SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi");

// Launch the process.
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/passive";
p.Start();
```

Additionally, you can use the [`ExpandEnvironmentVariables` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) with your original string like so:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = 
    Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%temp%\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%temp%` portion of the string is being interpreted literally instead of being replaced with the appropriate environment variable.  You'll need to manually expand it

```
var temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp");
var fileName = Path.Combine(temp, "SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi");
p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

%TEMP% is parsed and evaluated by Command Shell. You could use use [Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) and [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) for this purpose.

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), @"SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi");
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks! BTW: I changed string.Concat for Path.Combine, I think it is more appropriate here.

Comment: Path.Combine is almost always more appropriate than string.Concat when you are dealing with file or path names; it performs all of the path (and drive) separator logic for you, then does a string.Contact anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string tempPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp");
```

Then concat it in:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(tempPath, "SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi");
```

Casper beat me to the punch on the explaination, but the Process.Start method basically treats it literally instead of intrperting it as the shell would.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` to expand environment variables within a string, then pass that to the `Process` class:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%temp%\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi");
```

This has the added benefits of

1. Working for any environment variable (%APPDATA%, %COMMONPROGRAMFILES%, etc), and
2. Working anywhere in the string (e.g. "%temp%\%username%\foo.txt")