# Is the C# CMD/Process ever stateful? Do I ever need to consider state between two commands?

Tags: c#, process

I have a completely [different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891352) about HOW to reuse a cmd.exe process in C#.  But the goal of this one is to have a simpler question which will either make that other question moot, or will validate it's something I need to get answered.

**The question is this**: For everything related to a Process (hopefully platform agnostic, but I'm mainly focused on Windows right now), is it possible to use a brand new process for all subsequent commands?  For example:

```
dir /w

-- Get the output, see there is a folder called "LOLOL".
-- In a NEW cmd/process run:

cd LOLOL
dir /w
```

Obviously that will work using two different instances of the cmd/Process.

OR, are there specific examples where some first command (I am thinking some kind of Authentication) must proceed *In The Same Process Instance* some subsequent command?

Obviously this is a thing if you are using the command line to open up an SSH terminal.  But at that point isn't it true you're no longer on the process's CLI, you're in a sort of sub-application?  My question (I think) is mainly about typical commands directly on the Process / `cmd.exe` CLI.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking... but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013383/how-can-an-application-access-the-environment-variable-set-by-another-applicatio may be a related read.

Comment: One thing to note (which may or may not be pertinent) is that some commands that can be invoked at a `cmd.exe` command line can result in a new process starting, while others (like `dir` or `cd`) are implemented within `cmd.exe`

Comment: You can set variables, so that is state. And obviously anything you execute can have state.

Comment: @Charlieface - That is a good helpful bit to keep in mind.  AFAIK, setting variables applies to the system's Environment Variables, and would persist across instances.  Unless you are thinking about something else.  But I hadn't even thought of that, and it leads me down a good path.

Comment: `set` does not persist across consoles, only `setx`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1

Answer (score 2):

There are many facets to what you're asking and you're not being too clear of what you're trying to achieve here. At the very least, you have:

- console sharing. That's what your examples suggest, you're trying to allocate one console and share it between multiple processes? Kind of? `AttachConsole` will help with that, with a lot of steps to jump through if that's what you want. In Linux, you can use things like `screen` or `tmux`.
- command line interpreter sharing. Maybe what you want? In this case you'd start a `cmd` process and open its input and output pipes, then write in its input pipe the commands you want to run (`dir /w`) and read the output produced, then write another command and read its output and so on.
- security tokens sharing. Depending on your actual needs, you might be able to get away with the previous solution, but you're really in deep if you start doing it this way. You should get away from multiple processes and handle the environment and security context manually.

Comment: Thanks!! I WILL look into `AttachConsole`.  But the approach I'm taking is your 2nd point, which actually isn't possible.  *But that's a conversation for my linked other SO Question.*  My main Q here is whether or not I should even have to care about it.  Both Charlie's comment and your 3rd bullet are both stateless processes that read state from an external source (System/Environment Variables etc).  If there is truly no reason anybody relies on "state" within a single running process, My other Q may be able to be closed! :)